# Ruby Paypal SDK error - uninitialized constant PayPalSDKCallers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I am getting this error while using paypal mass payments API in rails.

```
uninitialized constant PayPalSDKCallers::Caller::PayPalSDKProfiles (NameError)
```

Any idea?
Thanks a lot for reading.

Anuprit

Comment: I got the same error, if you found solution. Please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same error and I fixed it by requiring the paypal-sdk-rest gem in the file where I was actually making the api call.
Hope this helps!